# Netbeans autocomplete on $this-> delegated object

Tags: php, netbeans

I am using Netbeans, and I love it.

However, my scenario is, when I want to use object B in object A, I can not use the autocomplete feature on `$this->B->`

(Yes, I know, the below code has syntax error, the question is not about syntax).

So, for example:

```
require_once('Legion.class.php');

class MyClass {

    private $Legion;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->Legion = Legion::getInstance();
    }

    public function showResult() {
        $this->Legion->   //Not works here

        $Legion = $this->Legion;
        $Legion-> //Works
    }

}
```

When I typed `$this->Legion->` I've got some basic functions, keywords, like `do`, `echo`, `while` etc...

But if I am create a new variable for this object B, then I've get back all of it accessable methods, and properties.

After this I've also tried to use `vdoc` without success:

```
/* @var $Legion Legion */
/* @var $this->Legion Legion */
```

Is somebody faced with this issue? Is there a solution for that?

Comment: Please add php-tag to your question!

Comment: It works for me, check this screenshot http://i62.tinypic.com/24xmb1y.jpg . The "ahoj" and "nic" comes from Legion class. It works even without the type hinting. Could you share the Legion class as well? And also which NetBeans of version do you have?

Comment: 8.0 I will check tomorow. 8.1 has a Nullpointer exception, this is why I downgrade to 8.0

Comment: Can you please add the code from: `Legion.class.php` Also do you use version: `8.0` exactly or something like: `8.0.1`? On which `OS` is Netbeans installed? And also where is your project located?

Comment: Now I have no code at here, at home, it's on github, just I want to tell you the exact params of my workplace machine. That is a laptop, win7 64bit, and it's 8.0 not 8.0.1. Tomorrow I will try what you suggest. Legion class is just a regular class with getters and setters. Tomorow I will post the code.

Comment: I meant, I would like to use my workplace machine, to be locate the problem as it is.

Comment: Can't reproduce your error, maybe try to provide more infos! (Maybe it's just a error which you can't reproduce so have you tried reinstalling Neatbeans? &&|| creating a new project and copying the code in to test it? )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use correct PHP Doc

```
 /** 
 * My Legion
 * @var Legion
 */
private $Legion;
```

-> http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/PHP/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.var.pkg.html

Comment: That do the job. Thank you.

Comment: Ha, the bounty is bigger then your current rep!

Comment: @Rizier123 How is it possible? Should I do something to give him the bounty, or is it automatically?

Comment: @lolka_bolka I'm not 100% sure, but i think you can manually award the bounty! (See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)

Comment: @BrainFooLong I've offered it, you solved my problem, so it is belongs to you :)